# Need help in a login sequence diagram

Tags: authentication, uml, sequence-diagram

hi everyone i'm à newbie in uml and my question is simple:i want to draw a sequence diagram for members login and the steps are as follows:

---

the member visits the login page

enters email/pwd

clicks login

then the system goes to the database

if record exists

if account active

```
  display login success msg
```

else (account not active)

```
  display error msg
```

else(record does not exists)

display error msg

---

and the diagram should contains the following objects:

- member
- login page
- System
- database

so can any one show me how it's done and thanks in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried without using if else statment

Comment: So you're just needing help with the if-else?

Comment: yeah that's it ...and don't get confused because i am just newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is simply not to use a sequence diagram for things which are better expressed in code like `if` and `loop`.  However, if there is a need for it, use fragments and put the according sections inside.

See [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) for examples.

Your case will start looking like this:

[image]

Comment: i know how to use one if else statement but ...  what i dont know is how to nest two if else statements together and yes there is a need for a sequence diagram in my case.

Comment: Simply nest the fragments. That's all. As said: the graphical representation does not really add value. It's much simpler to express that with code.

Comment: can you please just provide a picture that demonstrates my case and it doesn't have be a login cas just any sequence diagram with nested if else and thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem. Earning points by exchanging knowledge is one thing that drives SO :-)

Comment: what was that drawn with?

Comment: @IanVaughan Enterprise Architect. I have mixed feelings about this product. But most likely it's not the worst choice.