# Sequence Diagram: What is the difference?

Tags: uml, sequence, sequence-diagram, powerdesigner

I'm new to using Sequence Diagrams, and I'm trying to find references but too many things make me ambiguous. There are a number of questions that I will ask about this problem.

1. From this references [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680560/sequence-diagram-for-login-mvc-webapp) and [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962262/need-help-in-a-login-sequence-diagram) I see a difference between [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5fJ5.jpg) 1 and [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLNXG.png) . For image1 he use MVC method, and for image2 he just pass it to database, and last i found this image on google he using boundary, but on PowerDesigner i dont see boundary icons

[image]. 
Can you explain to me the difference between the three images?

2. Which should I use to create a login sequence diagram? In my case I will make "Web-based Monthly Report Archiving"
3. Can you give me a reliable reference for making Sequence Diagrams?

Comment: The icons for the boundary / controller / entity shown in the third diagram are not normalized, so don't be surprised to not have them in a modeler.

Comment: yup thanks bruno, maybe I should find more information about uml.

Comment: The icons for the boundary / controller / entity were defined by the Rational Unified Process, which is a methodology that emerged more or less together with UML.

Answer (score 3):

I always recommend reading some book explaining how to model system using UML. It makes things easier and you can find some on-line.

Ad1.

Sequence diagram is a method of showing the interaction in a specific sequence but it does not assume anything about methodologies or standards used during modelling. MVC is a standard unrelated to UML creating some best practices about how to design systems. Whether you use it or not is up to you (unless you're constrained by e.g. your company).
As already mentioned in a comment by bruno since MVC is not part of UML standard it does not have to be implemented in UML compliant tools. Yet since it's quite popular you may find it in many tools anyway.

Ad2.

It's up to you and your design decisions.

Ad3.

This page in general is not about suggesting sources for general things. As already mentioned above I would recommend reading some good book about modelling in general. My standard recommendations are Howard Podesva's "UML for the IT business analyst" and Craig Larman's "Applying UML and patterns". A direct reference about UML may be found on [this excellent page](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) but it will not tell you how to model or design, only how to depict your model properly on UML diagrams.

Comment: okay thanks, at least now I have gained some informations from you.

Comment: Aha, I was going to recommend the same page on uml-diagrams.org. Regarding your second question, I think you were asking for a recommendation of a tool. Again, that is generally considered [off-topic on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282983/are-recommendations-for-books-or-tools-off-topic). So let me hide [the link](https://modeling-languages.com/text-uml-tools-complete-list/) to a complete list of text-to-uml tools here in a comment.